# Ist 'humanitäre Katastrophe' eine sprachliche Katastrophe?

Tags: grammar, phrase

Seit Jahrzehnten regt mich der Begriff "humanitäre Katastrophe" auf, so als sei die Katastrophe humanitär.

Ist der Ausdruck sprachlich legal, oder so arm wie er mir vorkommt?
Muss es nicht eine "Katastrophe aus humanitärer Sicht" heißen?

Es fällt mir aber auf, dass es mehrere solcher Konstruktionen gibt, die mir jetzt, beim Nachdenken, alle unsauber vorkommen:

- islamischer Terror (der Terror geht doch nicht in Moscheen)
- ein musikalischer Offenbarungseid

Aber nochmal zurück:

Eine humanitäre Katastrophe kann man auch (wenn auch schlecht) so auffassen, dass wir hier eine Katastrophe haben, die, verglichen mit anderen Katastrophen, humanitär ist. So wie eine spätsommerliche Wetterkatastrophe, oder eine nächtliche.

Oder eine humanitäre Einstellung.

Ist das einfach eine 2polige Eigenschaft von Eigenschaftswörtern, oder sogar nur 2 Pole von einer 3poligen, 4poligen oder multipoligen Attributierung?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Problem mit humanitär ist, das humanitär "menschenfreundlich, wohltätig, mildtätig" bedeutet ([Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/humanit%C3%A4r)). Das ist ein grosser Unterschied zu den anderen genannten Beispielen. Bei "menschliche Katastrophe" versteht man ja noch, wie es gemeint ist, aber bei "menschenfreundliche Katastrophe"?

Comment: Im Sinne einer Eigenschaftsbeschreibung ist eine Katastrophe weder menschlich noch menschenfreundlich. Eine Situation kann aber sowohl unter dem Blickwinkel der Menschlichkeit als auch unter dem der Menschenfreundlichkeit eine Katastrophe sein.

Comment: Finde ich nicht. Sie kann die Menschenfreundlichkeit herausfordern. Oder eine humanitäre Katastrophe wäre es, wenn die verhungernden auf der Straße liegen, und Menschen, die helfen könnten, würden ignorant daran vorbeigehen und sich nicht drum kümmern. Ich glaube diese Antwort bringt meine Frage erst auf den Punkt.

Answer (score 19):

Ich halte das sprachlich für einwandfrei, da ein Verweis auf die Bezugsdomäne über ein Adjektiv gängig ist:

- sprachliche Katastrophe
- medizinisches Problem
- moralisches Dilemma  (z.B. in Abgrenzung zum finanziellen Dilemma)
- menschliche Tragödie (z.B. in Abgrenzung zur ökologischen Tragödie)

usw.

All diese Wendungen kann man mit gleichem Bedeutungsinhalt in "SUBSTANTIV aus ADJEKTIV Sicht" umformulieren. Insoweit verstehe ich nicht, wieso "humanitäre Katastrophe" und "Katastrophe aus humanitärer Sicht" hier ein Sonderfall sein soll, bei dem die eine falsch und nur die andere Fassung richtig sein soll.

Answer (score 7):

Die Konstruktion ist auch nicht mit allen Adjektiven üblich.

Vergleiche:

gesunde Probleme
gesundheitliche Probleme

Die Konstruktion wird also eher weniger verwendet, wenn es sich um ein reines Adjektiv handelt und eher mehr, wenn das Adjektiv von einem Substantiv abgeleitet ist, da eben *eine* Bedeutung von

> Substantiv+lich/isch/ig/..

den Sinn

> in Bezug auf Substantiv

hat.

Gerade die Endung von humanitär verträgt sich mit dieser Verwendung sehr gut.

Libertär heißt nicht frei, monetär heißt nicht reich, usw.

Da es eine Frage des Sprachgefühls ist, welche Adjektive man als von Substantiven abgeleitet empfindet und welche nicht, ist natürlich nicht jeder mit jeder Verwendung gleichermaßen zufrieden. Dass ein Wort je nach Kontext durchaus gegensätzliche Bedeutung haben kann, kommt generell öfter vor. Auch die Witze mit Kinderschnitzel versus Schweinsschnitzel fallen in diese Kategorie, die ja keineswegs tatsächliche Verständnisprobleme aufwirft.

Answer (score -5):

In meinen Augen ist das typische PR-Sprache für knackige Schlagzeilen.

Ein Beispiel auf noch niedrigerem Niveau wäre "Kinderpornographie" als Bezeichnung für die multimediale Dokumentation von Kindesmissbrauch.

Comment: Nun, "Kinderpornographie" ist ein zurecht kritisierter Begriff, dem stimme ich zu, aber eine "Dokumentation von Kindesmissbrauch" ist in doppelter Hinsicht kein Fortschritt: 1. ist eine Dokumentation etwas anderes - sie wird intentional als Dokumentation hergestellt, und will aufklären, was bezeichnete Videos oder Bilder nicht wollen. 2. Enthält das Wort Missbrauch implizit die Vorstellung eines regelgerechten Gebrauchs. Alkoholmissbrauch, beispielsweise. Aber auch wenn von Kindern Gebrauch gemacht wird, so will man das sicher nicht ausdrücken. Die Suche ist spannend, aber hier off topic.

Comment: Was ist am Begriff *»Kinderpornographie«* zu kritisieren? Kinder (im österreichischen Juristendeutsch: "unmündige Minderjährige") sind Personen, die ihr 14. Lebensjahr noch nicht erreicht haben und Pornographie ist die Darstellung von expliziter Nacktheit (Zurschaustellung von Geschlechtsorganen) und sexueller Handlungen mit dem Ziel beim Betrachter sexuelle Erregung hervorzurufen. Ich finde, damit ist auch ziemlich klar, was das Wort *»Kinderpornographie«* bedeutet. Dass die Existenz solcher Darstellungen zu kritisieren ist, steht außer Zweifel. Aber was genau ist am Begriff zu kritisieren?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast 
πόρνη (pórnē „Hure, Dirne“) und γράφειν (gráphein „schreiben, malen, zeichnen“)
– es geht dabei jedoch nicht um die Aufzeichnung der Tätigkeiten einer Hure, sondern um Kinder gegen ihren Willen. Daher denke ich, dass der Begriff "Kinderpornographie" ein Euphemismus ist.

Comment: @feeela: Ich habe erst vor kurzem im Fernsehen einen Bericht über dieses Thema gesehen. Demnach richten sich gegenwärtig rund 50% aller Anzeigen wegen Kinderpornographie gegen Kinder, die Nacktbilder und Videos von sich selbst in sozialen Medien verbreiten. Der folgende Bericht ist erst 2 Wochen alt: https://www.heute.at/s/nacktfotos-sexting-auch-kinder-sind-straftaeter-100259590 Da wird es dann schwierig damit zu argumentieren, dass diese Darstellungen gegen den Willen der Kinder entstanden sind. Darstellung expliziter kindlicher Nacktheit, und somit Kinderpornographie ist das aber ...

Comment: ... trotzdem. Es gibt mittlerweile sogar mehr unter-14-jährige Täter als über-40-jährige. Wenn man den Fachleuten glauben kann, nimmt dieser Trend stark zu und ist längst ein Teil der Jugendkultur. Bei oberflächlichem Medienkonsum könnte man zu der Einschätzung kommen, Kinderpornographie sei immer die Darstellungen von sexueller Gewalt an Kindern. Wenn Kinderpornographie aber tatsächlich so definiert wäre, würde der weitaus überwiegende Teil dessen, was jetzt als Kinderpornographie gilt, plötzlich legal sein. Ich glaube nicht, dass das die bessere Lösung ist.